# Regex: match, but not if in a comment

Tags: regex, comments

I have a file of data fields, which may contain comments, like below:

```
id, data, data, data
101 a, b, c
102 d, e, f
103 g, h, i // has to do with 101 a, b, c
104 j, k, l
//105 m, n, o
// 106 p, q, r
```

As you can see in the first comment above, there are direct references to a matching pattern. Now, I want to capture 103 and it's three data fields, but I don't want to capture what's in the comments.

I've tried negative lookbehind to exclude 105 and 106, but I can't come up with a regex to capture both.

```
(?<!//)(\b\d+\b),\s(data),\s(data),\s(data)
```

This will capture all but exclude capture of 105, but to specify

```
(?<!//\s*) or (?<!//.*)
```

as my attempt to exclude a comment with any whitespace or any characters invalidates my entire regex.

I have a feeling I need a crafty use of an anchor, or I need to wrap what I want in a capture group and make a reference to it (like with `$1`) in my lookbehind.

---

If this is another case of "regular expressions don't support recursion" because it's a regular language (a la automata theory), please point that out.

Is it possible to exclude the comments in 103, and lines 105 and 106, using a regular expression? If so, how?

Comment: @duedl0r This is the dumbest thing I've heard today.

Comment: @Tomalak can you handle language independent abstraction? :)

Comment: @duedl0r: Regex flavors vary so wildly between languages that it is essential to know which one the OP is using, otherwise there is a high probability that a specific solution isn't going to work.

Comment: I'm using Boost C++ 1.47.0 regex.

Comment: What does it mean by `data` here `(?<!//)(\b\d+\b),\s(data),\s(data),\s(data)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easy way out is to replace `\s*//.*` with the empty string before you begin.

This will remove all the (single-line) comments from your input and you can go on with a simple expression to match what actually you want.

The alternative would be to use look-ahead instead of look-behind:

```
^(?!//)(\b\d+\b),\s(data),\s(data),\s(data)
```

In your case it would even work to just anchor the regex because it is clear that the first thing on a line *must* be a digit:

```
^(\b\d+\b),\s(data),\s(data),\s(data)
```

Some regex engines (the one in .NET, for example), support variable-length look-behinds, your's does not seem to be capable of this, this is why `(?<!//\s*)` fails for you.

Comment: `^(?!//)(\b\d+\b),` and `^(\b\d+\b),` are *exactly the same* as `^(\d+),` - `\b` will match when you're at the start of the line or between a digit and a comma. Also, `(?!//)\d` is sort of a safe bet `:)`

Comment: @Kobi: Yes, that's what dawned on me as well. ;) But more generally speaking, if you *don't* know exactly what follows, a negative look-ahead is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply anchor the regex to the start of the line:

```
(?m)^(\d+),\s(\S+),\s(\S+),\s(\S+)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you could just anchor the expression at the beginning of the line (to get all the data):

```
^(\d+),\s(data),\s(data),\s(data)\s*(?://|$)
```

Or maybe you can use a proper CSV parser which can handle comments.

Answer (score 0):

One another way I have just used in the text editor with the regex when you don't have the regex look ahead/behind features is just use a sequence of these:

```
^[^\r\n/]*(/[^/])?[^\r\n/]*(/[^/])?my_search_sequence
```

It will ignore sequence of `/` splitted by not `/` character by maximum of 2 of them. If you want more, then just add more:

```
^[^\r\n/]*(/[^/])?[^\r\n/]*(/[^/])?[^\r\n/]*(/[^/])my_search_sequence
```

and so on.

Probability that your search word would be behind the sequence like these does reduce with the length of the regex.